# check datetime has day name or timezone using python

Tags: python, datetime, django-rest-framework

I am receiving 3 types of date format from the response.

1. `Tue, 24 Dec 2019 05:19:34 +0000 (GMT)`
2. `23 Dec 2019 08:00:10 -0500`
3. `Mon, 23 Dec 2019 08:00:10 -0500`

I have used the below code to convert given date-time into the python DateTime.

1. `date = datetime.datetime.strptime(receive_date, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)')`
2. `date = datetime.datetime.strptime(receive_date, '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')`
3. `date = datetime.datetime.strptime(receive_date, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')`

**But I don't find a way to check which format I am receiving from the response.**

Comment: You can try each of them and see which one does not fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/2.6.0/) to detect the date.

```
import dateutil.parser
d = dateutil.parser.parse(your_date_str)
```

Sample output

```
>>> your_date_str = 'Tue, 24 Dec 2019 05:19:34 +0000 (GMT)'
>>> d = dateutil.parser.parse(your_date_str)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 24, 5, 19, 34, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

hope this helps you